# including a class from another folder in Xcode Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have two folders under my project: WebServices and classes.
How would I include DriverServiceService (in WebServices), in XMLViewController.h (in classes)?

I used the following with no luck:

```
#import <../WebServices/DriverServiceService>
#import <"WebServices/DriverServiceService">
#import <DriverServiceService>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to import with without '<' and '>' and give the path as ../ if class is not in the root.

`#import "../WebServices/DriverServiceService"` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use classes that are in a folder other than the root of your project, you can drag in or "add existing files" to your project. Make sure the "copy" option is unchecked. Now your project references those files in the project while they remain in their original location.

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of Xcode, auto completion might not work. 
Let's assume that the classes you are going to import are named **"MyClass.h"** and **"MyClass.m"**

To import, you simply give the filename like following:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
```

Answer (score -2):

oops, nevermind

just learnt to use ""

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Good to have you here, but you should improve this answer. Describe what you did wrong and how you solved your problem. Right now your answer is useless for everyone that is not you. Remember, StackOverflow is not your personal help machine; it's more like a huge knowledge database for everyone. And if somebody else has the same problem your answer won't be helpful at all.